# Parallel loop in existing FHW zone - will this work?

Tags: heating, hydronic

I have a contractor renovating a space for my in-laws, and his plumber added two kick heaters and tied them into an existing FHW zone, but did it differently than I expected.  I expected him to tap into the return line (3/4" copper) and run the new heaters in series with the rest of the zone.  Instead, he tapped into that 3/4" return line, but put the kick heaters in parallel, and I don't see any flow restriction on the original line.  Therefore, I don't see how any hot water is going to get pushed through the new loop.  He's coming back next week to finish the job and I'm going to ask him about this, but want to learn what he might be trying to do so I can follow his explanations and make sure the job is done right.

Attached is a picture of the original return line, with the feed coming from the top right and flowing to the top left back to the boiler.  The two new tees can be seen dropping down from the return line and going off to the new kick heaters.  How in the world can this ever work without some flow restriction in between the two new tees?  What would push the water into the new loop?  It looks to me like it will happily cruise right past both tees and leave the new kick heaters out in the cold.

[image: parallel loop]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those might be "monoflo tees", that split the flow internally, some going straight through, some diverted to the radiator.  The second one (in the direction of flow) rejoins the flows.  A much closer look would confirm what they are.  They might say "monoflo" or there might be other markings, the most important one being an arrow showing the direction of flow.  Look for an arrow.

In a monoflo system there is no "return", there is a single loop of pipe that snakes, usually around the basement ceiling, and for every radiator (or sometimes for a pair or group of them) there is a pair of special tees that splits off some of the flow.  The radiators are not exactly in series or parallel with each other, it's a combination of those.

Comment: Interesting - I have never heard of those, so I'll investigate a bit and will ask the plumber on Monday.  Thanks!

Comment: Ask him what that tap is for.  If it's a drain why isn't it at the lowest point of the zone it is draining?

Comment: I think you're right.  I looked more closely at the tees and they both have arrows cast into them, both pointed toward the middle.  Good question about the tap as well.

Comment: I talked with the plumbers yesterday, and while they are not Monoflo tees, they are a very similar product.  They don't divert the water with a scoop like Monoflo tees, but they restrict the water flow which raises the pressure at the first tee so the water is diverted into the parallel loop for the new kick heaters.  Thanks for helping me understand the logic of this installation.